# make content links from side nav links, exclude certain tags not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a solution where I create links based off my side nav for my content area.  I have it working but I need to exclude certain tags but its not skipping over them.

```
$("#left_nav").find("a").each(function(){
    var linkText = $(this).text();
    var linkHref = $(this).attr("href");
    var html = $('#center_content').not("a, h1, img").html();
    var re = new RegExp(linkText, "gi");
    $('#center_content').html(html.replace(re, '<a href="'+linkHref+'">'+re.exec(html)+'</a>'));
});
```

The not("a, h1, img") is not working.  It is still replacing text in a link.  I want to skip replacing anything in an a, h1, or img tag.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KqBCF/

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

`$('#center_content').find('*:not(a, h1, img)').html();`

Because in your example you just selectind element with ID `'#center_content'`, without filtering elements inside it.

UPD:
http://jsfiddle.net/KqBCF/2/

Comment: I tried to filter this via the not(), I also tried your solution but that doesn't return the proper HTML.

Comment: Difference between `filter` and `find` that `filter` is filtering currently selected elements, but `find` finds it's chilndren.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for the clarification. Seems this does not return the original html it strips out all the html and returns just text.

Comment: Also, check out the jSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/KqBCF

Comment: Updated. But this method got it's own conses.